# Symfony security.yml Unrecognized options "check_path, login_path, provider" under "security.firewalls.secured_area.ldapsecure"

Tags: php, symfony

**UPDATE I never figured out why the below security.yml file didn't work, but I did learn some stuff along the way that might help someone in the future. I don't know if this 100 percent accurate, but it doesn't appear that the login_path and check_path keys work with route names, you need to use the actual paths (e.g. /login). Also the provider key should be at the same level in the yaml as pattern and anonymous, rather than under ldapsecure as shown below.**

I'm getting this error when trying to configure a custom authentication provider using Symfony 2.6.

```
Unrecognized options "check_path, login_path, provider" under "security.firewalls.secured_area.ldapsecure"
```

Here's my security.yml

```
security:
  encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
  providers:
    ldap_provider:
      id: ldap.security.user.provider
  firewalls:
    login_firewall:
      pattern: ^/app/login$
      anonymous: ~
    secured_area:
      pattern: ^/
      ldapsecure:
        check_path: app_security_login_check
        login_path: app_security_login_path
        provider: ldap_provider
    dev:
      pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
  access_control:
    - { path: ^/app/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

The ldapsecure "factory" class exists and if I change the getKey() method to return someone else, it breaks differently, so the ldapsecure is being recognized. But I can't see why it's not accepting check_path, login_path or provider. If I change ldapsecure to form_login, I don't get the error, it's just not using my authentication provider.

So I feel like I'm missing something, but don't know where to look at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ldapsecure` factory change the body of `addConfiguration` method to the following:

```
public function addConfiguration(NodeDefinition $node)
{
    $node
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode('check_path')
                ->isRequired()
            ->end()
            ->scalarNode('login_path')
                ->isRequired()
            ->end()
            ->scalarNode('provider')
                ->isRequired()
            ->end()
        ->end();
    }
```

This should make it work.